# how to make a function that generate a matrix from the input scalars integers

Tags: matlab, function, matrix

i am going to make a function called `mymat` that takes two positive integer scalars, `n` and `m`, in that order as input.

The function must create and return `mymat`, which is an `n-by-m matrix`. Every element of board is either 0 or 1. The first element, `mymat(1,1) is 1`. No direct neighbours in the matrix, vertically or horizontally, can be equal. That is, a 1 element cannot have 1 immediately preceding or following it in the same row or column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to try this:

```
function [ mymat ] = mymat( n,m )
mymat=zeros(n,m);
for i=1:2:m
    mymat(1,i)=1;
end
for i=1:2:n
    mymat(i,1)=1;
end
for i=2:n
    for j=2:m
        if (mymat(i-1,j)==1)&&(mymat(i,j-1)==1)
            mymat(i,j)=0;
        else
            mymat(i,j)=1;
        end

    end
end


end
```

Comment: i did, why you take out accepted answer from my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

So you want a matrix of this kind :

1 0 1 0 1....

0 1 0 1 0...

1 0 1 0 1...

. . . . .
?

EDIT: I think that is the shortest and most instinctive way I found :)

```
function[mymat] = mymat(n,m)
a = ones(n,m);
b = 2:2:n;
c = 2:2:m;
a(:,c) = 0;
a(b,:) = 0;
a(b,c) = 1;
mymat = a;
end
```

Comment: You can look now if you like it.

Answer (score 0):

**`mymat.m`** function

```
function [ out ] = mymat( n,m )
    temp = repmat([1 0; 0 1],ceil(n/2),ceil(m/2));
    out = temp(1:n,1:m);
end
```

**Results:**

```
>> mymat(4,7)

ans =

 1     0     1     0     1     0     1
 0     1     0     1     0     1     0
 1     0     1     0     1     0     1
 0     1     0     1     0     1     0
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use toeplitz function

```
>> toeplitz(mod(1:4,2), mod(1:7,2))
ans =
     1     0     1     0     1     0     1
     0     1     0     1     0     1     0
     1     0     1     0     1     0     1
     0     1     0     1     0     1     0
```

You can have it as an anonymous function like

```
mymat = @(n,m) toeplitz(mod(1:n,2), mod(1:m,2))
```

or, as a separate function

```
function M = mymat(n,m)
M = toeplitz(mod(1:n,2), mod(1:m,2));
end
```

Answer (score 0):

With [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
mymat = mod(bsxfun(@plus, (1:n).', 1:m) + 1, 2);
```